# Konvajs. Как получить объект при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Работаю с konva
У меня есть массив квадратов такого типа

```
let square= new Konva.Rect({
              x:cur_x,
              y:cur_y,
              width:seg_size,
              height:seg_size,
              stroke:"black",
              fill:"green",
              name:"rect"
          });
```

Получаю я их всех так:`var s=stage.find(".rect");`
Теперь мне надо при нажатии на один из квадратов получить его позицию.
Делаю так

```
s.on("click",()=>{
   console.log(this.getClientRect().x)
});
```

Но получаю `TypeError: this.getClientRect is not a function.`
Как получить елемент находящийся в массиве(группе)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цитата из [документации к стрелочным функциям](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> Выражения стрелочных функций имеют более короткий синтаксис по сравнению с функциональными выражениями и лексически привязаны к значению this (**но *не привязаны к собственному this*, arguments, super, или new.target**). Стрелочные функции всегда анонимные.

Попробуйте заменить на 
`s.on("click",function () {
   console.log(this.getClientRect().x)
});`